# What's the name of this property?

Tags: order-theory

Is there a name for (partially or totally) ordered set $(A,<)$ such that for any $x,y\in A$, $x< y$ there is a $z\in A$ such that $x<z<y$?

Comment: I don't know if there is an especially snazzy name for this property, but you could rephrase it by saying that *all maximal elements are minimal*. Less elegant formulations include *all maximal elements are incomparable to other elements* and *all maximal upper bounded chains have at most one element*.

Comment: The way you've phrased the question, there's no poset that satisfies this condition (aside from trivial examples like singletons), because it implies in particular that for all $x,y\in A$, $x\ne y$ implies $x<y$.  Would you like to rephrase?

Comment: @JackLee: Good point!  I misread that myself: I read it as "for any $x,y\in A, x\lneq y$...".  This needs to be clarified/confirmed before my previous comment can be used!

Comment: @Unwisdom Fixed the typo. I have no idea why I typed $\ne$ instead of $<$.

Comment: @JackLee Fixed the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order

From Wikipedia : "In mathematics, a partial order < on a set X is said to be dense if, for all x and y in X for which x < y, there is a z in X such that x < z < y."

Comment: But the property in this case is not density - it postulates the existence of a $z$ greater than $y$, not between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, "density"! It's just that I've heard this property being called "continuity" by non-math people in arguments so often that I forgot the actual name.

Comment: Well done @user3211995 for answering the question that was intended rather than the one that was actually asked!  Is there a badge for being psychic?

Answer (score 0):

This would be that no chain has a maximal element, the opposite conclusion of Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: The criterion read $x<y<z$ at time of posting.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.